# Python built in sum function

Tags: python

I have a simple question for python:

say I have `A = [1,2,3,4]`, and I want to sum elements of from the second and third entry. How can I do this in python? `sum(A[i] for i in [1:2]) = 2 + 3 = 6`doesn't work.

Comment: `A[1] + A[2]` will work just fine. Additionally, `2 + 3` sums up to `5` and not `6` like in your question.

Comment: A[1:2] has just a single element, A[1].

Comment: `sum(A[1:3])` ? Lower slice is inclusive, upper slice is exclusive.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski why dont you wrote it as answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because `[1:2]` is **not a legal expression on its own** in Python:

```
    [1:2]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## The fix

```
sum(i for i in A[1:3])
```

will work.

## The better solution

```
sum(A[1:3])
```

Read up on list slicing in  [an informal introduction to python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

That's invalid syntax, You can use:

```
sum(A[i] for i in [1,2])
```

or:

```
sum(A[i] for i in range (1,3))
```

or with slice:

```
sum(i for i in A[1:3])
```

Last index in slice is not included.

(or like a comment below says, simpler is: sum(A[1:3])

The reason your code is invalid is slice cannot be on its own. It has to be said it's a slice of what, e.g. A[1:3] is a slice of A, but [1:3] says nothing about elements of what it should take. Second problem is with indexing, like I mentioned, last one is not included.

Comment: Even simpler : sum(A[1:3])

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(A[1:3])
```

> A[1:3] means slicing list from index 1 to 3[3 is exluded]

Read about list slicing.

Best wishes !

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 sum([A[item] for item in [1,3] ])
```

I don't think there is a simpler solution to this.

Comment: Sadly,a downvote without a comment serves no purpose.

Comment: You don't need a list comprehension for that

Comment: Simpler : sum(A[1:3])

Comment: This is the right answer if you need to sum an arbitrary subset of the list items; it's not clear from the question if that is the case, or if a sublist is wanted (in which case slicing is far simpler).

Comment: I assumed that the items to be added are not always continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a contiguous range of items from the list, use a slice:

```
sum(A[1:4])  # A[1] + A[2] + A[3]
```

If the set of indices is *not* contiguous, use a list comprehension

```
indices=[1,5,7]
sum(A[i] for i in indices)
```

or `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig
indices=[1,5,7]
sum(ig(*indices)(A))
```

--

It is, perhaps, a shame that the `list` type cannot accept a tuple as an index, treating `A[1,5,7]` as `[A[1], A[5], A[7]]` instead of a type error.